# How to get the exit status of second last command?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run 2 commands and output the exit status of the first command. And all this, I want to do it in a single line of command.
Something like this

```
cmd1; cmd2 && echo $?-1
```

It should output the exit status of cmd1.

Comment: What are you trying to do by `echo $?-1` btw

Answer (score 10):

Like any other global variable that has its status updated over time (ie. `errno` in C), if you want to refer to an old value, you need to store it ahead-of-time.

```
cmd1; cmd1_retval=$?; cmd2 && echo "$cmd1_retval"
```

---

The place where this is different, by the way, is in a pipeline:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
echo "${PIPESTATUS[$(( ${#PIPESTATUS[@]} - 2 ))]}"
```

That's because in a pipeline, all components run at once, and by default the exit status is that of the last one. In bash, however, the exit status of all components is stored in the `PIPESTATUS` array; `${#PIPESTATUS[@]}` takes the length of this array, and subtracting two from it (one because of the difference between 0- and 1-based indexing, and one to get from the last item to the second-to-last item) gets the second-to-last item in the preceding pipeline.

Comment: Would this still output the exit status if `cmd2` fails?

Comment: @EricRenouf, it doesn't, but that's what the OP appears to want -- otherwise, why would they have used `&&` in their code in the question?

Comment: Well, one reason is because they admitted to not knowing how to do it, but agreed that yours is in keeping with the sample code from the OP

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd1; status=$?; cmd2 && echo $status
```

Comment: All-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or OS, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed not to interfere with system operation; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two commands as follows where you are checking the version of the first command to see if you have the correct version of the command installed:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

cmd1="my_command version"
cmd2="sleep 1"
exit_code=$(${cmd1}; status=$?; ${cmd2} && echo $status)
printf "_${exit_code}_"

if [[ "_${exit_code}_" == "_0_" && "$(my_command version)" =~ " 1." ]]; then
   my_command
fi
```

The output could be the following if `version` was a valid option or command of `my_command`, where `my_command 1.0.0` is the output of `my_command version` and `0` is the exit code at the end. Note that I have used surrounded the value with `_` just to make it clear:

```
_my_command 1.0.0
0_
```

And that would not satisfy the first condition of the `if` statement.

But the output could be the following if the version of `my_command` that was currently installed was a different version that only supported use of the option `--version` and so use of `my_command version` was invalid:

```
_1_
```

To resolve that issue I simply got the exit code from the last character with `last_char=${exit_code: -1}` and changed the first condition of the `if` statement to be `"_${last_char}_" == "_0_"` instead

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

cmd1="my_command version"
cmd2="sleep 1"
exit_code=$(${cmd1}; status=$?; ${cmd2} && echo $status)
last_char=${exit_code: -1}
printf "_${last_char}_"

if [[ "_${last_char}_" == "_0_" && "$(my_command version)" =~ " 1." ]]; then
   my_command
fi
```